# Efficiently check for equal adjacent values in raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, raster-calculator, nearest-neighbor, map-algebra

I have a raster consisting of integer values in each cell. I want to check every adjacent cell in a 3x3 grid to see if **any** one of the adjacent cells has a value EQUAL to the center cell, and if so, give the output raster a value of 1 (else give it a value of 0). I have already accomplished this like so:

```
Con("raster" == FocalStatistics("raster", NbrIrregular("C:\filepath\kernel_file.txt"), "MAXIMUM"), 1, 0)
```

Where the kernel file looks like this:

```
3 3 
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Then again for another possible combination:

```
3 3 
0 1 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

And so forth:

```
3 3 
0 0 1
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Then I have to combine all of the rasters at the end to get one final raster.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? It shouldn't be necessary to loop through the raster this many times to get what I need. Raster calculator solutions will work, but ArcObjects solutions are welcome as well as the end result will likely end up being implemented in ArcObjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [focal *variety*](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qs000000.htm) (in a 3 by 3 neighborhood) remains the same when the center is not used (for a focal variety in an annular 3 by 3 neighborhood) if and only if the center cell is duplicated in one of the neighboring positions.  This solution requires just two neighborhood calculations and a comparison.