# Performing Raster Calculator functions using Python and open source modules?

Tags: python, pyqgis, open-source-gis, raster-calculator

I would like to perform mathematical functions similar to those you would use Raster Calculator for in ArcMap, however I'd like to do it in Python without using the ArcpPy module. I have the osgeo module, and it seems like it should be possible to do however I'm having a hard time finding any useful syntax.

An example function would be to multiply every cell value in an input raster by 2.

Comment: There is a nice example of accessing rasters through the GDAL GeoTIFF driver here (see the answer that was awarded bounty): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72183/how-do-i-iterate-through-every-cell-in-a-continuous-raster

Comment: You can also access the QgsRasterCalculator Class using Python.  More details here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/59305/8104.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without reinventing the wheel, I suggest you to use [**gdal_calc.py**](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py). Example:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*2"
```